# добавление массива на страничку

Tags: javascript

Есть массив. Нужно чтобы при загрузке странице он добавлялся в 3 разные карточки.

```
const cards = [
  {
    name: 'name1',
    text: 'text1'
  },
  {
    name: 'name2',
    text: 'text2'
  }, 
  {
    name: 'name3',
    text: 'text3'
   }
];
```

Comment: А шаблон? Как добавлять должен?

Comment: Создать блок. Допустим card-list. Нужно чтобы в него добавлялись 3 карточки. если допишу еще одну в массив,то еще одна карточка. name- в див с классом card_name.    а text - в див text_name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const cards = [{
    name: 'name1',
    text: 'text1'
  },
  {
    name: 'name2',
    text: 'text2'
  },
  {
    name: 'name3',
    text: 'text3'
  }
];

const card = document.querySelector('.card');

let append_html = '';

cards.forEach(card => {
  append_html += `
    <div>
      <p class="name">${card.name}</p>
      <p class="text">${card.text}</p>
    </div>
    <hr>`
});

card.innerHTML = append_html;
```

```html
<div class="card"></div>
```

Comment: cпасибо большое